# How to Declare table to variable in MARIADB/MYSQL for function/procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, function, mariadb, procedure

I don't know how to operate MySQL DECLARE THIS TABLE?

```
MS_SQL CAN 
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE 
(variable INT)
```

But `MySQL` can't do this! How can i do it?

Syntax error !!

Comment: I have tried to make your question clearer by some formatting and grammar corrections.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have the feature of declaring a variable for a table. Variables can only be scalars.

If you need a feature that Microsoft SQL Server supports, then you should use Microsoft SQL Server.

Also when you use `DECLARE` in MySQL, you can't use the `@` sigil on variables. Local variables in stored routines don't have that sigil in MySQL. This is another difference from Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make a table or database name come from an argument or variable, you will need to

1. Construct the query, probably using `CONCAT`.
2. `PREPARE` the query.
3. `EXECUTE` the query.
4. `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`.