# Getting a syntax error when declaring a table in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

New to SQL and trying to run this code and I get the error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@Qtable TABLE(Qid INT) END' at line 3".  The code runs fine if I take out the `DECLARE` statement;

```
SET @query_id = (SELECT ID from ua820988_dev.users WHERE `email` = 'example@gmail.com');
CREATE PROCEDURE query_requests()
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Qtable TABLE(Qid INT)
END;
SELECT * from ua820988_dev.requests WHERE `match` = @query_id;
SELECT * from ua820988_dev.requests_archive WHERE `match` = @query_id;
```

I'm hoping to eventually put the results from the 2nd and 3rd `SELECT` statements into the table, but this is the watered down version for now just trying to get the code to run.  I'm running SQL 5.6 on MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: First, time to upgrade!  (see note under "February 1, 2021" on https://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html ), but  I notice that for 10.2 you have until 23 May 2022 (https://endoflife.date/mariadb) Please delete the tag `mysql5.6` or the tag `mariadb-10.2`, and only keep the tag for the database that you are using!)

Comment: Why do you want to DECLARE a variable that you do not use?  It is not in use in the code you provided so far , an creating a procedure which only declares a variable is (at least a but, strange.

Comment: @Luuk, I'll eventually use the variable, I just want it to get past this point before I start writing the code to use it.

Comment: Are you sure MariaDb even supports this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58279983/73226

Comment: I do not see `TABLE` between the datatypes (see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/data-types/) and `ROW` is there but it is supported from version 10.3+

Comment: Thanks, MartinSmith and Luuk, that would be the problem!